# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$ converge and does it converge to $0$ ?. I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$ converges on $Re(s) > 1$ to $\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}{(1-\frac{1}{p_j^{s}})}$ (here of course $p_1, p_2,...$ are the distinct primes)  and taking $s \rightarrow 1^{+}$ suggests $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = 0$ but this is not rigorous and probably incorrect.

Comment: What on earth is $\mu$?

Comment: The mobius function; $\mu(j) = 0$ if a prime squared divides $j$. One has $\mu(j) = 1$ if $j$ is a product of an even number of distinct primes and $\mu(j) = -1$ if $j$ is a product of an odd number of distinct primes.

Comment: the statement above is a version of PNT so true but quite non-trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Conrad explained in a comment, it is indeed correct that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = 0,$$ and moreover, this result is equivalent to the Prime Number Theorem. This proof and its connection to the Prime Number Theorem have been discussed many times on this site. See for example Peter Humphries' response to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433631/proving-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-mu-nn-0-where-mu-is-the-m%C3%B6biu?rq=1) question.

For some references where you can see a detailed proof and learn a lot more about this, see Calum Gilhooley's response to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169675/a-proof-of-sum-mun-n-0) question.

Comment: There are two parts here - convergence and equivalence to PNT and usually the second (elementary manipulations but convoluted, Landau, 1912) is shown in standard textbooks, while first is then deduced from the usual proofs of PNT. Ingham proved in 1935 (Newman simple proof in 1980) the Tauberian theorem: If $f$ Dirichlet series with bounded coefficients (hence converging absolutely for $\Re s >1$) can be extended analytically in the neighbourhood of ANY point on $\Re s =1$, then $\Sigma{\frac{a_n}{n}}$ converges (to $f(1)$ by easy Abelian results); using $f=\frac{1}{\zeta}$ gives the result