# Can we prove that partial sum $|\sum_1^N \mu(n)/n| \le 1/2$ when $N > 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta, mobius-function

Here, $\mu(n)$ is Möbius function.

From [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/an-elementary-inequality-involving-the-mobius-function/amp/), we can see that partial sum $|\sum_1^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n}| \le 1$. when $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

We also know the series converges to $0$ and is not monotone.

Is it known if the partial sum $|\sum_1^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n}| \le \frac{1}{2}$ when $N > 1$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$. I have confirmed that this bound holds for $1 < N \le 50,000,000$, and the absolute value of partial sum gets much much smaller that 0.5 when N gets to 50 million. But that doesn’t mean it will necessarily hold to all $N$s to infinity. I’m wondering if there is a way to prove it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169675/a-proof-of-sum-mun-n-0

Answer (score 1):

The convergence of $\sum_n \mu(n)/n $  is equivalent to the PNT and its proof gives an explicit decay. Yes checking to $10^7$ is enough but proving so is complicated.

(you can deduce the latter claim from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function#Known_upper_bounds )

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How can one convert an upper bound for $M(x) = \sum_1^x \mu(n)$ such as $|M(x)| < x/4345$ when $x > 2160535$ to any assertion for upper bound for $m(x) = \sum_1^x \mu(n)/n$? I can prove computationally that $|m(x)| < 0.1$ when $6 < x < 7\cdot 10^7$ where do I go from there with the known  upper bound of $|M(x)|$? Thank you!

Comment: May be Theorem 3.13 in Titchmarsh will help. If I can calculate the bound for large enough x that is less than 1/2 and then supplement it with calculations up to that x, it should suffice. I just hope the large x required for 3.13 is not too large.